# Selenium takes 30s to realize an element id doesn't exist. What should I do?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I'm using Selenium to scrape / parse an awful web site (if it wasn't awful, I might not use Selenium, and yes, respecting robots.txt).

I'm reading a set of links from a table of unknown size, with sequential element ids, using `find_element_by_id()`. I'm catching `NoSuchElementException` to tell me that I'm at the end of the table and there are no other elements to pick up.

This smoothly walks through the elements that exist, but takes about 30 seconds to throw the error when I request the non-existent element that tells me I'm at the end of the table.

The file is not that huge - the html dump from DOM Inspector delivers a 81kb file. The last link in the table (which Selenium finds quickly) is 7/8s of the way through the file, so (assuming Selenium is parsing sequentially) file size alone doesn't seem to explain this.

Can I speed up the failure of finding the missing element? Or is there a more elegant way to know I am in the last row of the table with content?

Comment: e.g. can I use a wild-card to get all the matching elements at once? They look something like blah_blah_21_blah_blah where 21 is the 21st element.

Comment: Do you have this line `driver.implicitly_wait(30)` in your code

Comment: Yes at wild card matching. Search by css selector. Example `find_elements_by_css_selector("[id^='blah_blah']")`

Comment: @Amey, yes I do - I guess this means it is waiting to see if more of the page is going to load everytime I request a non-present element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do this using css selectors instead.

```
driver.findElements( By.cssSelector( '[id^=id_name]' ) )
```

Comment: What is the difference between find_elements_by_css_selector and findElements(By.cssSelector()) ? The second one raised an error, but perhaps I did not import the FindElements function - couldn't figure out where to find it.

Comment: @pnj `findElements` is java syntax, `find_elements_by_css_selector` is python syntax.